# CSS: Line break before element if last in row

Tags: html, css, line, anchor, break

I have images as inline-block elements in a grid-like gallery and at some points in code there are hidden elements that are basically anchors that serve as navigation through different years that pictures were taken.

The problem is when the first image of the next year gets placed as first element in a row, the anchor elements stays behind in a previous row. What I want to do is stick the anchor element to the next element (image) so it breaks with it.

I'm open to CSS and JS. I realize there are better ways of doing this, but changing HTML code is not an option as it is a part of a bigger structure and even minor changes would probably cause other scripts to fail.

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 250px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button href="#2015">2015</button>
  <button href="#2016">2016</button>

  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <div id="2015"></div>
  <!-- Anchor element -->
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <div id="2016"></div>
  <!-- Anchor element -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 250px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <a href="#2015">2015</a>
  <a href="#2016">2016</a><br/>

  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="..."><br/>
  <div id="2015"></div>
  <!-- Anchor element -->
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <img src="..." alt="..."><br/>
  <div id="2016"></div>
  <!-- Anchor element -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That would cause a break on every anchor. What I'm trying to do is exactly this but only if the anchor element is the last in line.

Comment: Image last html tag use <br/> and next line .

Comment: 1. Same problem. There would be a break even if the the anchor isn't the last element in a row.
2. Like I said, changing the HTML is not an option.
Still thank you.